# Confusion with polar coordinate vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics

Ok, I'm trying to understand the newton's law in terms of polar coordinate.

As far as I understand, in polar coordinate the vectors are represented as r direction and $\theta$ direction.

My question is, when we differentiate the position vector $\hat{r}$ in order to find velocity vector, $\dot{\hat{r}} = \frac{d}{dx}(r\hat{r}) = \dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\hat{r}} = \dot{r}\hat{r} +r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}   $, right?

I can understand the process here.

My confusion is, maybe this is really stupid question, if position is represented as r direction and $\theta$ direction, then isn't it should be like, $\hat{r} = (r,\theta) = r\hat{r} + \theta\hat{\theta}$ ?

Then why velocity vector is not $\dot{\hat{r}} = \frac{d}{dx}(r\hat{r}+\theta\hat{\theta}) = \dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\hat{r}}+\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}+\theta\dot{\hat{\theta}}    $ ???

Why we considering only r direction when we calculate velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the position is always $\vec{r} = r \hat{r}$ where $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector pointing toward the object $\hat{r} = (cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$, $\hat{\theta}$ is defined to be always perpendicular to $\hat{r}$ (i.e. $\hat{\theta} = \hat{k} \times \hat{r}$)

your confusion is this statement "if position is represented as r direction and θ direction" which is wrong, position is just $r$ magnitude in the direction of $\hat{r}$ **which is defined to always point directly towards the object**.

another thing is the derivative is always taken with respect to time $t$ not to $x$ (which could be confused with the x coordinate)

Comment: Oh so if unit vector r=(cos(theta),sin(theta)), then r itself can represent a point on a plane uniquely with certain theta. I'm still bit confuse, but I think I kinda understand where I was lost. Thank you very much!

Comment: But if this is the case, then polar coordinate cannot be defined without help of cartesian coordinate? since r=cos(theta)xhat+sin(theta)yhat? I thought polar coordinate was stand-alone coordinate system.

Comment: different coordinate systems are related to each other through different transformations, none is superior to another, we find cartesian coordinates more intuitive because they are probably simpler (and maybe because we are taught them first), however it really depends on the problem/phenomena and which coordinates system is more suitable(natural?) to it whether it's cartesian, polar, cylindrical, spherical or others, it really depends on the problem and all of these can be tranformed into each other.